# Uniqueness of a solution and its form

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have the following equation :

\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \ u(x) = e^{-|x|} + \beta\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-|x-s|}u(s)ds,
\end{equation}
with $\beta > 0,\  \beta \in \mathbb{R} $ and $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

I need to prove that the solution of the equation exists and is unique. To prove that it exists, I rewrote the expression as such : 
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad u(x) = f(x) + \beta (f * u)(x),
\end{equation}
$f(x)$ being equal to $e^{-|x|}$. By applying the Fourier transform to both sides (both $u$ and $f$ being integrable), I obtain:
\begin{equation}
\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \hat{u}(\xi) = \frac{2}{1+\xi^2} + \frac{2 \beta}{1+\xi^2} \hat{u}(\xi)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Longleftrightarrow \hat{u}(\xi)\Big(1-\frac{2\beta}{1+\xi^2} \Big) = \frac{2}{1+\xi^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Longleftrightarrow \hat{u}(\xi) = \frac{2}{1-2\beta+\xi^2}.
\end{equation}
This expression is well defined when $\beta \neq \frac{1+\xi^2}{2}, \ \ \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}$. $\ \beta$ being strictly greater than $0$, and $\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}, \ \frac{1+\xi^2}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2}$, I deduce that for $\beta \in \Big(0, \frac{1}{2} \Big)$, the problem has a solution.

How do I prove the uniqueness of the solution? 
I tried setting $v$ just like the initial equation and then subtracted $v$ from $u$, but I'm stuck from there on. I was also wondering what is the solution? Many thanks.

Note: I used the following result in my calculations:
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{F}\Big(e^{-|\xi|} \Big) = \frac{2}{1+\xi^2}.
\end{equation}

Comment: In order to apply the Fourier transform to both sides, you are implicitly assuming that the solution exists.

Comment: @copper.hat Isn't it okay to assume apriori the solution exists and find the explicit form of the solution and say that it does indeed exists?

Comment: @JackyChong: You are correct, it was a nitpick on my part. To be pedantic, we could 'guess' what the Fourier transform is as above, but we should verify that the inverted function actually satisfies the equation and is integrable. The point being that the proof of existence is the explicit $\hat{u}$ above, not the derivation preceding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove the existence and uniqueness using a Banach fixed-point argument.

Let us define a map $\Phi:L^1(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^1(\mathbb{R})$ by
\begin{align}
[\Phi(u)](x) = e^{-|x|} +\beta \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-|x-s|}u(s)\ ds
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\|\Phi(u)-\Phi(v)\|_{L^1} \leq&\ \beta \left\|\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-|x-s|}[u(s)-v(s)]\ ds\right\|_{L^1} = \beta\|e^{-|\cdot|}\ast[u-v]\|_{L^1}\\
\leq&\  \beta\|e^{-|\cdot|}\|_{L^1}\|u-v\|_{L^1} = 2\beta\|u-v\|_{L^1}.
\end{align}
Thus $\Phi$ is a contraction mapping provided $0<\beta<\frac{1}{2}$. Hence by the Banach fixed point theorem there exist a **unique** $\phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that
\begin{align}
\phi(x) = e^{-|x|}+\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-|x-s|}\phi(s)\ ds. 
\end{align}

Note: I have used the inequality
\begin{align}
\|f\ast g\|_{L^1} \leq \|f\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^1}. 
\end{align}